# DoWhile Loop Stuck while using colMonitoredevents

Tags: vba, directory, monitor

I am using a script to monitor a folder for addition of files. The script runs fine if 3 files (meeting the conditions) are added to the monitored folder. It nicely extracts the data from these files and adds to the open excel file. But if the conditions are not me the script keeps going through the `Do While Loop` and I am unable to use any buttons on the excel (Was thinking of using another command button to exit the loop).  Please Help!! Any suggestions are appreciated! Thanks!

```vb
Public vItem As Variant
'vItem contains the folder path that the user selects.  
'Another function deals with this and only its values is passed to `CommandButton2 Click()` 

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
Dim fcounter, pcounter, vcounter As Integer
    fcounter = 0
    pcounter = 0
    vcounter = 0



Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Dim vItemstr As String
vItemstr = Replace(vItem, "\", "\\\\")
MsgBox vItemstr



Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
    ("SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 10 WHERE " _
        & "Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' and " _
            & "TargetInstance.GroupComponent= " _
                & "'Win32_Directory.Name=" & Chr(34) & vItemstr & Chr(34) & "'")



Do While True

    Set objLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent
    StrNewfile = objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.PartComponent


    arrNewFile = Split(StrNewfile, "=")
    strFileName = arrNewFile(1)
    strFileName = Replace(strFileName, "\\", "\")
    strFileName = Replace(strFileName, Chr(34), "")
        Dim justfilename, namestr As String
            justfilename = Dir(strFileName)
            Do While True
                     novaval = InStr(1, justfilename, "SampleResults")

                             If novaval > 0 Then
                                     namestr = "f"
                                     Exit Do
                             End If
                     novaval = InStr(1, justfilename, "v")
                             If novaval > 0 Then
                                     namestr = "v"
                                     Exit Do
                             End If
                     novaval = InStr(1, justfilename, "p")
                             If novaval > 0 Then
                                     namestr = "p"
                                     Exit Do
                             End If
            Loop

        If namestr = "f" And fcounter = 0 Then
            i = i + 1

            Dim OpenFileName As String
            Dim wb As Workbook

                Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strFileName, UpdateLinks:=0)
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("K18:P18").Value = wb.Sheets(1).Range("G1:L1").Value
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("K19:P19").Value = wb.Sheets(1).Range("G5:L5").Value
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("K20:P20").Value = wb.Sheets(1).Range("G4:L4").Value
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("K21:P21").Value = wb.Sheets(1).Range("G3:L3").Value
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("K22:P22").Value = wb.Sheets(1).Range("G2:L2").Value
                    ThisWorkbook.Save
                wb.Close
            fcounter = fcounter + 1
        ElseIf namestr = "v" And vcounter = 0 Then
                i = i + 1
                Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strFileName, UpdateLinks:=0)
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C18:E18").Value = wb.Sheets(1).Range("C1:E1").Value
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C19:E19").Value = wb.Sheets(1).Range("C5:E5").Value
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C20:E20").Value = wb.Sheets(1).Range("C4:E4").Value
                    ThisWorkbook.Save
                wb.Close
            vcounter = vcounter + 1
        ElseIf namestr = "p" And pcounter = 0 Then
                i = i + 1
                Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strFileName, UpdateLinks:=0)
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("F18:H18").Value = wb.Sheets(1).Range("X1:Z1").Value
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("F19:H19").Value = wb.Sheets(1).Range("X5:Z5").Value
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("F20:H20").Value = wb.Sheets(1).Range("X4:Z4").Value
                    ThisWorkbook.Save
                wb.Close
            pcounter = pcounter + 1

        End If


        If i = 3 Then
            Exit Do
        End If


Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: First, you have not shown Dim's for several variables, so don't know what they are. Second, are you sure the 'Exit Do' is truly getting you out of the loop? You have TWO 'Do While True' loops. If you put a breakpoint in and don't have the required three files, it should show where the problem lies.

Comment: Thanks Wayne for your comment! I noticed that `vItem` description was missing so I edited the post to clarify that variable.  I went through the code again and was unable to find any other variable which is not declared.  If you would be kind enough to point that out I will edit the post to clarify those variables. You have a good point regardin the other `Do while` loop.  Let me take a look. But regardless, even before I added the other loop as soon as the monitor is turned on nothing on the excel file is 'clickable' until the monitoring has finished.

Comment: Add 'Option Explicit' at top of module, then 'Debug | Compile'. Will show the missing Dim's.  You should be able to place a breakpoint in your code at the first 'Do While True', then click the button to start the process. Then in the code window, just press F8 to step through the code. Should be easy to find the issue. Finally, your 'Do While True' seems a little strange because you have no condition that will ever alter the 'True' condition - thus the loop will run forever until you 'Exit'. If you said 'Do While blnFlag = True' and you alter blnFlag in the loop, then that will stop the Do.

Comment: The last `If` statement just before `Loop` all the way at the bottom of the code is what ENDS the `Do While True` loop. Basically what it does is that as soon as 3 files are added to the monitored folder (each one of them containing 'f' or 'p' or 'v' in their filename) the `Do While True` loop breaks.  What I wanted was another option where the user can manually break the `Do While True` loop using a commandbutton for example.  But unfortunately as I mentioned above as soon as the loop starts I am unable to click on any controls on the excel sheet.

Comment: (1) The following are not defined (did you ever use Option Explicit and compile??):  objShell, strComputer, objWMIService, colMonitoredEvents, objLatestEvent, StrNewfile, arrNewFile, strFileName, novaval; (2) Did you ever attempt to step thru the code using a breakpoint? (3) If you fix the code, no need to provide ability to 'break'. Possibly you could use a timer, plus DoEvents, to MAYBE let user interrupt.

Comment: Also, since you fire this code by a button click, what do you want to happen if the three files don't exist? Keep looping until they do (forever??)?.  I see why the loop never ends if the three files don't exist, so what do you want to have happen? To exit 'i = 3' must be true, so how long do you wait if you don't have all three files?

Comment: I apologize I am bad at explaining since I am not a fulltime programmer.  I  learnt VB probably 10 years ago. Right now I am just writing some scripts to make few tasks in our lab easy.As you just mentioned, the loop doesn't end until i=3. I could easily use a timer but I want to have an option where the user can interrupt.  All the code containing StrNewfile, arrNewFile, strFileName, novaval variables is not neccesarily relevant to the issue.  The only thing I don't know is how to have the user interrupt such that the loop breaks.

Comment: The following article is what prompted me to use this code for monitoring folder      http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/04/21/how-can-i-monitor-a-folder-for-the-creation-of-new-subfolders.aspx

Comment: I don't mind helping others, but it becomes time-consuming if suggestions are not followed and questions go unanswered. Option Explicit is not 'the answer', but it is a useful tool for determining if variables are correctly defined. Stepping through the code would quickly show why the loop never ends (I faked this on my PC). In the end, you need to decide what to do if the three files don't exist: (a) exit the subroutine and tell the user (THIS IS MY CHOICE), or (b) keep waiting - possibly forever - for the file to appear.

Comment: Thanks for your time and willingness to help! I really appreciate it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can stop the looping (but I really wish you would answer the question of what should happen if all three files are NOT present - exit? Wait?)

Place the following at the form level (i.e. at the top of the module - outside of all subroutines):

```
Dim fvStopTheLoop              As Boolean
```

Inside the Sub cmdStart_Click, insert the following:

```
fvStopLoop = False
```

After EACH of your 'Do While True' statements, add the following line:

```
DoEvents
```

Where you have 'If i = 3 then', replace like the following:

```
    If i = 3 Then
        Exit Do
    End If
    If fvStopLoop = True Then
        MsgBox "Ending the loop due to user request", vbOKOnly, "End"
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Add a new command button with the following code:

```
Private Sub cmdStop_Click()
    fvStopLoop = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments Wayne!  To answer your initial question - `but I really wish you would answer the question of what should happen if all three files are NOT present - exit? Wait?`  Well if the 3 files are not present then I would definitely like to exit ..that is the ONLY difficulty I am facing.. Unfortunately even with the code you provided it doesn't work.. As mentioned in my initial post... as soon as the monitoring starts all the buttons on the excel page are not clickable.. so there is no way for me to click the cmdSTOP button to end the loop..

Comment: Well, I intentionally misspelled a variable just to see if you ever tried using 'Option Explicit' to look for undefined variables (see several of my earlier posts asking you to try that). The code I provided DOES work if you correct the spelling.

Comment: I understand that you had asked me to declare the variables which I did.. and I fixed "mispelled" variable .. still your code didn't work since once you click on the cmdbutton which initiates monitoring everything on the excel form becomes unclickable until 3 files are added to the folder .. which means that the cmdSTOP button is also not clickable and that is why your code is not working. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: I have another workaround this issue but it is not elegant at all where I pop up a vbyesno dialog box (Do you want to terminate monitoring?) so if the user clicks Yes then the monitoring ends with "Exit Do". But the user clicks No then it continues with the loop ... the only problem is that when the files are finally added, for each file the dialog box appears to which the user has to keep clicking "No" to successfully import values from the files added.  But it does work.. it won't be elegant if I create a code for more than 3 files

Comment: The reason for the 'hang' is line 'Set objLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent' which is going to sit and wait until a file is created. If you want the user to wait (forever?) leave the code as-is... otherwise you need to consider a whole new approach (i.e. use FSO to spin through list of files)

Comment: Hi Wayne, Is there a way to put a 2min timer? or even that is not possible since the hang starts as soon as code hits `Set objLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent` ?

Comment: Ivan F Maola discusses how to terminate such code here http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/211547-monitor-new-files-folder.html#post1037155 but to be honest I don't understand his code for termination

Comment: As Ivan stated, the method of monitoring the folder causes a 'hang' condition until an event takes place (add/delete file) -- hence his suggestion to move to a script. Unless I have missed something in your 'requirements', why can't you just use FSO to check for the three files? Very simple to do - assuming there is some clarity added to the requirements.

Comment: Hi Wayne.. I actually used another method to achieve the same task.  Instead of having a code monitor the folder I gave an option to the user where he can select multiple files to import and based on the filename I sort out the data in the appropriate cells. It is working like a charm! Thanks again for all your comments and advice, I really appreciate it!